# Change Opengl ES 2.0 coordinate Origin

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

in Opengl ES 2.0, is there a simple way to change the bottom left origin to be instead the Top Left when drawing? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use simple vertex shader, adding some logic to make tex top-right corner to be in proper position.

```
attribute vec4 position;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main()
{
    texCoord = position.xy * vec2(1.0, -1.0);
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

and pixel shader just taking those texCoord and passing to sampler.

```
varying vec2 texCoord;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, texCoord);
}
```

Comment: I see a problem, that the position is a vec4, and this will fail to fit into texCoord which is a vec2. I don't know if is a typo or should be instead something else

Comment: @Zhenya it is a typo since you are drawing a quad you need only xy coordinates. updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For regular drawing operations by applying an appropriate projection matrix, or flipping the Y coordinate in the vertex shader. You didn't specify what projection you use and didn't post code, so that's the answer I can give you.

Comment: I have a quad I am drawing into it a bitmap. The problem is that I should paint it from the top-left corner, but opengl draws it from the bottom-left corner. As a note, the bitmap is smaller than the quad, but I need it to be painted from the top-left, so the empty areas not filled by the bitmap are the right and bottom of the quad.

Comment: @Zhenya: Thanks for the explanation, but if you added some code of what you tried so far to your question, I could modify a little bit.